Increase the size of column name cells in a table
How can I increase the size of only the cells that contain the name of the columns in a table? (in the photo are Impiegto, Progetto and Funzione)

This is my LaTeX overleaf code:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c |c | c |}
\hline
Impiegato & Progetto & Funzione \\
\hline
Rossi & Marte & Tecnico \\
Verdi & Giove & Progettista \\
Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
Neri & Venere & Direttore \\
Neri & Giove & Consulente \\
Neri & Marte & Consulente \\
Mori & Marte & Direttore \\
Mori & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Giove & Direttore \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
\label{relazione_con_anomalie}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i did, I'm really sorry for the mistake

Thanks for the update! With "increase size", do you mean to make these cells taller or so you want to increase the font size?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz with "increase size" I mean increasing the space that is present below and above the text

You could switch to the tabularray package and use row{1}={rowsep+=5pt} to add additional space above and below the first row:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|c |c | c |},
  row{1}={rowsep+=5pt}
}
\hline
Impiegato & Progetto & Funzione \\
\hline
Rossi & Marte & Tecnico \\
Verdi & Giove & Progettista \\
Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
Neri & Venere & Direttore \\
Neri & Giove & Consulente \\
Neri & Marte & Consulente \\
Mori & Marte & Direttore \\
Mori & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Giove & Direttore \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
\label{relazione_con_anomalie}
\end{table}
\end{document}


If your actual question is how to increase the white space around all horizontal lines:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=0pt}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|c |c | c |},
  hborder{1,2,Z}={abovespace+=5pt,belowspace+=5pt},
}
\hline
Impiegato & Progetto & Funzione \\
\hline
Rossi & Marte & Tecnico \\
Verdi & Giove & Progettista \\
Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
Neri & Venere & Direttore \\
Neri & Giove & Consulente \\
Neri & Marte & Consulente \\
Mori & Marte & Direttore \\
Mori & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Giove & Direttore \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
\label{relazione_con_anomalie}
\end{table}
\end{document}



am I wrong or with this code have all the cells in the table increased in size? I intend to increase only the cells that contain the text "Impiegato", "Progetto" and "Funzione"

@Andrea The default value for tabularray is bigger than in traditional tables. See my updated answer, although personally, I find the more airy spacing more pleasant for reading.

is it possible to add a small space to move the line below "Impiegato, Progetto, Funzione" with the text below? same thing for the last line of the table with the text above

@Andrea row{2}={abovesep+=5pt},  row{Z}={belowsep+=5pt}

@Andrea From your comments, it seems that you don't actually want to increase the space above and below the text, but around the lines. If that's true, see my updated answer

You can use an invisible rule to stretch only the heads, but it seems, the other rows should also be stretched a bit, so I'll combine both. And it seems the head should use a sans-serif font and maybe bold. So I've added this, too:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\newcommand*{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.6ex}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}% stretch all rows
\begin{tabular}{|c |c | c |}
\hline
\tabhead{Impiegato} & \tabhead{Progetto} & \tabhead{Funzione} \\
\hline
Rossi & Marte & Tecnico \\
Verdi & Giove & Progettista \\
Verdi & Venere & Progettista \\
Neri & Venere & Direttore \\
Neri & Giove & Consulente \\
Neri & Marte & Consulente \\
Mori & Marte & Direttore \\
Mori & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Venere & Progettista \\
Bianchi & Giove & Direttore \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Esempio di relazione con anomalie.}
\label{relazione_con_anomalie}
\end{table}
\end{document}


If you want only one of the stretches, you can remove the \rule[…]{…}{…} or the \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{…}. Feel also free to play a little bit with the values.
